# Writing Selection Logic in Where Statement of T-SQL

Tags: logic, case, selection, where-clause

I am wring a query where I need to compare the patient encounters with particular set of physicians and use a logic to select the patients.

Fields:

1. Account ID
2. Service Date
3. Latest Service Date for the Account
4. Service Counts by Billing Tech
5. Total Service Counts for the Account ID
6. Billing Tech ID

--- Wouldn't let me paste the screenshot here... :(

logic

if an account holder saw one billing tech for maximum number of times then, select that row

OR

if an account holder saw more than one billing tech for the same number of times, then select the row that has the latest service date from those billing techs (i.e. saw tech A, tech B, tech C for  two times each, then select the row that has the latest service date within those three billing tech service dates)

I need help with the logic. I am confused on how to write my logic within where statement.

Anyhelp is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you,

Comment: Wouldn't let me add screenshot of the output...I am so sorry it's looking the way it's looking now...

Comment: I'd like to understand the data a bit more first. I can imagine a table with Account ID, Service Date and Billing Tech ID -- each row would record one service transaction. The other three fields you list look like derived/calculated rather than raw data. But are you implying that all 6 fields are columns in a single table?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COUNT(*),BillingTechID,LatestServiceDatefortheAccount 
GROUP BY BillingTechID,LatestServiceDatefortheAccount 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

I hope understand your question correctly.

Comment: I need to select the row, not count the number of accounts by billing ID. Each row has account ID and each row has Service Counts by Billing Tech, Total Service Counts for the Account ID, and Billing Tech ID. The logic should evaluate each and every row and select the row based on the logic. Also, the output should have only  distinct number of account IDs, their Billing Tech ID, and the Service Date.